# how to hide External URL while redirecting in angular

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, navigateurl

Trying to redirecting to External URL but URL should be hidden or dummy URL should be in address bar
I have used window.location.href = URL; this is working but URL is visible and have lost control to angular application.